# How to prevent Vim scrolling when splitting a window?

Tags: vim

I want to stop Vim from scrolling (if that's the right word) when I split a window horizontally.

Let's say I edit a 10 line file in Vim.  I have a single window onto the buffer and the window is 40 lines high.  There's more than enough room for two windows, one on top of the other, with both showing the whole buffer.  And let's say `scrolloff` is set to 4.

When I split the window horizontally, the original window is scrolled so that exactly `scrolloff` lines are shown between the top of the window and the line the cursor is on -- if there were more than `scrolloff` lines between the top of the window and the cursor line -- even though there is no need to scroll.

Put another way, if the cursor is on line 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 when I split the window, the original window doesn't "move" (good).  But if the cursor is on line 6, the window scrolls so that line 2 becomes the top-most visible line...ensuring `scrolloff` lines (4) are visible above the cursor line (annoying).  Similarly if the cursor is on line 7 when I split the window, the original window scrolls to that line 3 becomes the top-most visible line.  And so on.

Is there a way to configure Vim never to scroll the original window when I split it horizontally?

I imagine it's possible to map `<C-W>s` to a function which does what I want, but I'd prefer to solve this by configuration if possible.

Comment: Isn't it a direct effect of scrolloff?

Comment: It happens even when `scrolloff` is 0 (i.e. has never been set).  Also `scrolloff` is supposed to be the minimal number of lines to keep above/below the cursor, not the exact number.

Comment: You could `set scrolloff=999` which is often used to keep the current line in the middle of the window. It seems to solve your problem but it can be super annoying.

Comment: It does not scroll when you split vertically with `set nowrap` (with `set wrap` it may scroll, but not too far) and it makes perfect sense because number of lines does not change. Making vim *never* scroll on horizontal split is impossible because number of lines will change. And you are wrong saying about “scrolling to exactly `scrolloffset` lines”: when splitting horizontally it tries to keep the *proportion*: if in 65 lines high window cursor is on 44’th line after split it is on 22’nd. If `winline()/2` appears to be lesser then or equal to `&scrolloffset` then you will get your behavior.

Comment: I didn't realise Vim tried to keep the proportion when splitting horizontally.  Is that documented anywhere?

Comment: @ZyX is it possible to (elegantly) suppress this behaviour, so that the topmost visible line prior to splitting is still the topmost visible line after splitting?

Comment: @ChrisWilson No idea whether you can make vim *try* to do so, but it is impossible to split like this *every time* without moving the cursor. I am almost absolutely sure that vim has no options for moving the cursor in case of split, and don’t remember option for making it try to keep the topmost line.

Comment: @ZyX, splitting vertically or horizontally, with or without `wrap`, worked fine for me in an older version of vim, never changing the position at all. After upgrading I get this annoying bug that Andy is talking about, for both vertical and horizontal splits. Using `set nowrap` has no affect on the split with my current setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Vim 9.0.0667 and Neovim 0.9 you can try

`set splitkeep=screen`

Read more at `h splitkeep`

Comment: with `screen` it does seem to move cursor( reproducible with horizontal slit. with `cursor` it keeps the cursor on same line but moves the view to the center.

Answer (score 6):

I've found a solution, borrowing the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3933547/151007).

In my `.vimrc` I have:

```
nnoremap <C-W>s Hmx`` \|:split<CR>`xzt``
```

And now when I split the window horizontally with `<C-W>s`, the original window doesn't scroll at all.

Comment: This is the solution I went with for now, but when using `:wincmd s`, which I have to do on my Chromebook because `<C-W>` will try to close the window, I still get the annoying change. Also, when this does work,  with `<C-W>`, the screen will flash, whereas an older setup of vim worked fine. I'm thinking there is a hard-to-find or undocumented setting somewhere that might fix this, unless it's a legit vim bug.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to [Andy Stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151007/andy-stewart)'s solution here's what I use in my `.vimrc`:

```
                      (3)          (5)
                      ++          +--+
                      ||          |  |
nnoremap _ Hmx``<C-w>szz<C-w><C-p>`x``<C-w><C-p>
           |   ||    |  |        |    |        |
           +-+-++----+  +--------+    +--------+
            (1)  (2)       (4)            (6)
```

(1) Go top left save mark it to `x` and go back to where you were.
(2) Create a new split. Cursor will move to this new split window.
(3) Use `zz` to center the cursorline.
(4) Go back to the window you have created the split.
(5) Go back to `x` mark and then go back to where you were (to simulate step (1))
(6) Go back to the split you created.

One addition I made is to add `zz` onto the newly opened split to make the cursor on the new window easier to catch. My brain can automatically focus onto the center row of the new split.

Answer (score 4):

A recently available option is the [stable-windows](https://github.com/gillyb/stable-windows) plugin. I've tried it and it's working well.

Comment: Is it just me or does this not work when switching back and forth between buffers?

Comment: It's working for me when moving between buffers. If you can reproduce an issue I'd recommend filing an issue for the plugin on it's github page.